# Implementing WebSocket Broadcasting in Laravel for Real-Time Updates when Creating New Games

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

"I'm developing a multiplayer card game using Laravel, and I'm struggling to implement WebSocket broadcasting for real-time updates. Specifically, I want to notify all connected clients when a new game is created, but I'm unsure how to integrate WebSocket broadcasting into my application flow.

Currently, I have a create function that generates a unique access code for the game and attaches the creator as a participant. However, I need to broadcast a message to all clients when a game is created, and I'm not sure how to accomplish this using Laravel WebSocket Broadcasting.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Facades\WebSocketsRouter;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Game;
use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\Channels\ChannelManager;
use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Facades\WebSocketsBroadcaster;


class GameController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $accessCode = $this->generateUniqueAccessCode();

        $game = Game::create([
            'access_code' => $accessCode,
            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        ]);

        $game->participants()->attach(auth()->id());

        if ($game->participants->count() >= 4) {
            $game->update(['status' => 'started']);
        }

        WebSocketsBroadcaster::broadcastToAll([
            'event' => 'game.created',
            'game_id' => $game->id,
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('game.show', $game->id)->with('success', 'Spiel erfolgreich erstellt und beigetreten!');
    }
}
```

Use of unknown class: 'BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Facades\WebSocketsBroadcaster'

I've already installed the beyondcode/laravel-websockets package and configured it according to the documentation, but I'm unsure how to trigger WebSocket events when creating a new game.

Could someone provide guidance or examples on how to properly integrate WebSocket broadcasting into my Laravel application to achieve real-time updates when creating new games?

Answer (score 0):

In my past mature and stable projects, I recommend using pusher/pusher-php-server and soketi. You need to understand private and public channels.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).